# Can I use SQL view in left outer join with ordinary table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-view

This is my view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW w AS SELECT
orp1.order_product_id,
orp1.order_id,
pov1.weight,
sum(orp1.quantity) AS 'quantity'
FROM
`order_product` orp1,
`order_option` oro1,
`product_option_value` pov1
WHERE
pov1.option_id = 6 AND oro1.product_option_value_id = pov1.product_option_value_id AND orp1.order_product_id = oro1.order_product_id
GROUP BY
orp1.order_product_id,
orp1.order_id,
pov1.weight;
```

This is query part

```
FROM 
    `order_product` orp6,
    `product` p,
    `product_description` pd,
    `product_to_category` p2c
LEFT OUTER JOIN w ON orp6.order_id = w.order_id AND orp6.order_product_id = w.order_product_id
```

But the error displayed is :

> **orp6.order_id** *is unknown column*

Comment: The error complains about a table's column, not the view

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your queries are invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Scope issue. Explicit JOIN chains are evaluated before the comma separated tables. orp6 columns are not available in that LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also you are not clear. Why do you say "This is query part"? What is that code? Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of things to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  In this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW w AS
    SELECT orp1.order_product_id, orp1.order_id, pov1.weight,
            sum(orp1.quantity) AS 'quantity'
    FROM `order_product` orp1 JOIN
         `order_option` oro1
         ON orp1.order_product_id = oro1.order_product_id JOIN
         `product_option_value` pov1
         ON oro1.product_option_value_id = pov1.product_option_value_id
    WHERE pov1.option_id = 6 
    GROUP BY orp1.order_product_id, orp1.order_id, pov1.weight;
```

You can then add additional `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause, such as the one you want add.

Comment: [I need comlex query optimization](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C9WybTXua9fKl6fmHyzEoTlndEPX08MyL1N2lCkVPQU/edit?usp=sharing). I created stored procedure and moved the query code to the procedure. Also maked views for put in selects

Comment: @ВладимирАфанасьев What is the point of your comment? You state some things, but so what? See the comments on the question: Comma binds looser than JOINs. So if you want the left input to the LEFT JOIN to be the cross join of the tables between the commas then replace the commas by CROSS JOIN.